# Sigma Lens for Nikon AF D

Tags: nikon, sigma

I have nikon D3400 and an extra sigma lens 70-300mm DL Macro Super. They are not compatible because the lens does not have a built in af motor and d3400 also does not have af motor in it. Is there any extension or adapter that would make these 2 compatible? THANKS

Comment: I think I have the Pentax version of that lens (adapted to Fuji X) Mine is manual focus. Does yours not have manual focus?

Answer (score 2):

Your left hand is the only adapter available to focus that lens on that camera. Before the mid-1980s, everyone had to focus that way.

Here are some questions regarding doing manual focus with the cameras we had back then as well as with more modern DSLRs:

[How did photography work before auto-focus was invented?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/82512/15871)
[Can viewfinder type make an appreciable difference in manual focus?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/95132/15871)
[Why don't DSLRs come equipped with "classic" focusing screens (split prism, etc)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11621/15871)
[Disadvantages of split-prism focusing screens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3223/15871)
[Do focusing screens exist for modern DSLRs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/60178/15871)
[What is a focusing screen?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/23862/15871)
[What are the differences between different types of focusing screens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/60774/15871)

[Supermoon: In focus and Out of focus](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/84500/15871)
[This answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/79158/15871) to [What are some alternatives if you don't have a flip screen in your camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/79144/15871)
[How do you manually focus accurately without a focusing screen?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2275/15871)
[Catadioptric lens: equivalent focal length and focus at infinity](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/93559/15871)
[Why do some lenses focus past infinity?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/40995/15871)

[Why are photos taken with my old lenses all out of focus on my new Nikon D5300 body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/67461/15871)
[Does the Sigma 70-300 AF-D work on the Nikon D3200?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/75623/15871)
[Will a AF VR_Nikkor 80-400mm 1:4.5-5.6D lens work on a Nikon D3400?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/94935/15871)